# Using Spotify on Zombies 5K

Tags: android, zombies-run

I got Zombies 5K some time ago through a Humble Bundle but I noticed that I can't use a Spotify playlist while playing it / running. While the free version of Zombies! Run! has support for external playlists, Zombies 5K doesn't (and it's a paid version). Since I have almost no locally stored music on my device I was wondering if it's in any way possible to use a Spotify playlist since running in almost complete silence is quite boring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zombies, Run 5k does not support using a cloud service (Spotify, Google Play Music) to play music in the app.

In order to play music in this app you need to create a play list with local music by plugging your phone into the computer and copying some music files to it.

Comment: I have several offline playlists on Spotify but they are still not picked up by the game.

Comment: @DGarvanski Do not have the playlist on Spotify, make the playlist on WinAmp or any other music player which isn't a cloud based service

Comment: I removed the last paragraph, because it seems that spotify playlists are encrypted and will not work.

Comment: Yeah, they are encrypted. I tried looking through the Android/com.spotify.music folder and all locally saved files all have the .file extension so I guess it's not possible to use Spotify on Zombies! Run! 5K. That's really dumb since it's the paid version, but oh well! Guess I'll have to download the free version and get ads and, possibly, micro-transactons...